# Inserting values from an array into a SQL query

Tags: php, sql, arrays

how do i get the array value from below code?. and use `while loop` to save the data those are not empty.
not quite sure what needs to be added from the code.

```
if(!empty($bookslot['t_deep'])) :
  $tw_deep = 'deep_wrap';
elseif(!empty($bookslot['t_eyelashes'])) :
  $tw_eyelashes = 'eyeLashes_wrap';
elseif(!empty($bookslot['t_holistic'])) :
  $tw_holistic = 'holistic_wrap';
elseif(!empty($bookslot['t_male_nail'])) :
  $tw_male_nail = 'male_nail_wrap';
endif; 

$arr[]  = array($tw_deep, $tw_eyelashes, $tw_holistic, $tw_male_nail);

$db->query("INSERT INTO checked_treatments (treatment_group, id_treatment, id_booking, b_ref) VALUES('$arr', '1','$id_bookslot', '$b_ref')");
```

in the treatment_group, the array returns `Array instead of 'deep_wrap, etch..`

expecting for database :

```
    Array          1   123  abc // <-- result above code
--------------------------------------------------------
    deep_wrap      1   123  abc
    holistic_wrap  2   123  abc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want to do is this (i think):

```
$arr  = array($tw_deep, $tw_eyelashes, $tw_holistic, $tw_male_nail);
$arrPlode = implode(', ', $arr);

$db->query("INSERT INTO checked_treatments (treatment_group, id_treatment, id_booking, b_ref)
                  VALUES('$arrPlode', '1','$id_bookslot', '$b_ref')");
```

here is a demo with a query echo: http://codepad.org/3NgGu1Tm

**OR**

make a new query for each if:

```
if(!empty($bookslot['t_deep'])) {
  $db->query("INSERT INTO checked_treatments (treatment_group, id_treatment, id_booking, b_ref) 
      VALUES('deep_wrap', '1','$id_bookslot', '$b_ref')");
}
if(!empty($bookslot['t_eyelashes'])) {
  $db->query("INSERT INTO checked_treatments (treatment_group, id_treatment, id_booking, b_ref) 
      VALUES('eyeLashes_wrap', '1','$id_bookslot', '$b_ref')");
}
if(!empty($bookslot['t_holistic'])) {
  $db->query("INSERT INTO checked_treatments (treatment_group, id_treatment, id_booking, b_ref) 
      VALUES('holistic_wrap', '1','$id_bookslot', '$b_ref')");
}
if(!empty($bookslot['t_male_nail'])) {
  $db->query("INSERT INTO checked_treatments (treatment_group, id_treatment, id_booking, b_ref) 
      VALUES('male_nail_wrap', '1','$id_bookslot', '$b_ref')");
}
```

**OR CONCATENATE THE QUERIES:**

```
$concat = array();

if(!empty($bookslot['t_deep'])) {
  $concat[] = "('deep_wrap', '1','$id_bookslot', '$b_ref')";
}
if(!empty($bookslot['t_eyelashes'])) {
  $concat[] = "('eyeLashes_wrap', '1','$id_bookslot', '$b_ref')";
}
if(!empty($bookslot['t_holistic'])) {
  $concat[] = "('holistic_wrap', '1','$id_bookslot', '$b_ref')";
}
if(!empty($bookslot['t_male_nail'])) {
  $concat[] = "('male_nail_wrap', '1','$id_bookslot', '$b_ref')";
}

$db->query(build_insert_query('checked_treatments', 
         'treatment_group, id_treatment, id_booking, b_ref', $concat));


function build_insert_query($table, $cols, $values){
        $return = "INSERT INTO $table ($cols) VALUES";
        $val_length = count($values);
        foreach($values as $key=>$val){
             $return .= $val;
             if($key < ($val_length-1)){ $return .= ", ";  }
        }
        return $return;
}
```

here is a demo of the above with fake values: http://codepad.org/ox4kG43b

Comment: @Neal: thanks:) but i want the result store in each row, not to be one row.

Comment: @Neal: perhaps you have another solution, please share :)

Comment: @Neal: thanks for the effort :D. i guess thats the only way ;)

Comment: or you can do one more thing. give me a minute

Comment: @Neal: wow ur star :D .. so i just change the table name here `($table, $cols, $values)`?

Comment: you can build any insert query with that function i just gave you, as long as all the parts are formatted correctly

Comment: @boyee, i added a demo at the end that you can play around with

Comment: @Neal: have u got any email or msn that i can add :D. well if that ok ffor ya

Answer (score 0):

drop the square brackets on the declaration to be. You are making a 3 dimensional array otherwise

```
$arr  = array($tw_deep, $tw_eyelashes, $tw_holistic, $tw_male_nail);
```

And in your query you still need to dereference the array to get the value by specifying the index

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO checked_treatments (treatment_group, id_treatment, id_booking, b_ref) VALUES('$arr[0]', '1','$id_bookslot', '$b_ref')");
```

An index of 0 will return the value of `$tw_deep`